# OAuth через соц.сети (Facebook, VK, Одноклассники). С мобильного браузера, авторизацию нужно перенаправлять на приложение

Tags: авторизация, oauth

На мобильных устройствах нужно реализовать OAuth через соц.сети (Facebook, VK, Одноклассники). С мобильного браузера, авторизацию нужно перенаправлять на установленное приложение соц.сети, и авторизоваться через него обходя открытие новой вкладки в браузере (потому что, с мобильных устройств редко кто в соц.сетях сидит в браузере значит с авторизацией могут быть проблемы). Из приложения ссылкой должно идти обратно на сайт.

Comment: Вы не задали вопрос, а просто описали механизм. В чем состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: Прощу прощения, вопрос в том: возможно ли в принципе, авторизироваться через приложение с браузера?